# Dimensions of Thule skewer/rear axel?

Tags: trailer, skewer

I recently bought a new bike and I would like to attach the Thule wagon hitch to it. However, my skewer on the rear wheels is a bit short when I attach the hitch to it. It would be good of my skewer was 2-3mm longer.

This is my existing skewer, I'm not completely sure how you are supposed to measure it. The complete length is about 180mm long and 10mm in diameter:

[image]

So I guess I would need something like 82mm or something but looking online, no such thing is sold anywhere. Then I noticed that Thule’s themselves sells a skewer but they failed to mention the dimensions anywhere. Does anyone have it and could take measurements of it?
https://www.thule.com/en-us/bike-trailers/bike-trailer-accessories/thule-axle-mount-ezhitch-cup-with-quick-release-skewer-_-20100796